# Clarity textarea height to fit wizard page height

Tags: javascript, css, angular, vmware-clarity

Using Clarity and Angular 9, I have a button in the main content area which opens the wizard. Now in the wizard, I have a textarea which I want to fill the wizard content area. I'm able to get the width of textarea working by setting width: 100%.

But I am not able to get the same thing working for height.

Here is the stackblitz link which shows the problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-form-reset-xtyait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textarea` get the size from it's parent.

Some css togehter with [Angular `::ng-deep`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) wil do it:

```
::ng-deep .clr-control-container {
  height: 100%!important
}

::ng-deep .clr-textarea-wrapper {
  height: 100%!important
}

::ng-deep .clr-form-control {
  height: 100%!important
}

::ng-deep .clr-wizard-content {
  height: 100%!important
}
```

Here is your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-form-reset-e2hwuy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) with resized textarea.

Comment: Is  `!important` really required? You should give it higher specificity instead. https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/ I'm almost tempted to downvote because `!important` is such bad practice, a lot like `eval`